# Can't split pandas dataframe because some rows are interpreted as int?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to `Python` and having difficulty with the following bit. I have a data with the following structure:

```
customerId    products
0    20
1    2|2|23|68|68|111|29|86|107|152
2    111|107|29|11|11|11|33|23
3    164|227
5    2|2
6    144|144|55|266
```

I just want to split the products column by `|`. So I run the following code:

```
transactions['products'] = transactions['products'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split('|')])
```

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'*

Looks like rows similar to the first one are interpreted as `int`. I filtered my data on `excel` (this time included only rows that had at least one `|`), ran the same code and had no problem.

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert values to strings before `split`:

```
f = lambda x: [int(i) for i in str(x).split('|')]
transactions['products'] = transactions['products'].apply(f)
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split('|')]
transactions['products'] = transactions['products'].astype(str).apply(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
transactions['products'] = transactions['products']\
      .apply(lambda x:[ int(y) for y in x.split('|')]
transactions.head()
Output:
   customerId                                   products
0           0                                       [20]
1           1  [2, 2, 23, 68, 68, 111, 29, 86, 107, 152]
2           2         [111, 107, 29, 11, 11, 11, 33, 23]
3           3                                 [164, 227]
4           5                                     [2, 2]

type(transactions["products"][0][0])
Output:
<class 'int'>
```